# Unable to format json data in php

Tags: php, json, parsing, retrofit2

I am working on retrofit. I am fetching data from online server using **php**, but my **json** is not formatted correctly. So many people have asked this question but no one answer is working for me.

Here is my php code

```php
    <?php
    header("Content-type:application/json");

    require_once('connect.php');

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `retrofit` ") ;

    $response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

        array_push($response,
        array(
            'userId' =>$row['userId'],
            'id' =>$row['id'],
            'title' =>$row['title'],
            'body' =>$row['body']));
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

And here is the output:

> [{"userId":"1","id":null,"title":"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit","body":"quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"},{"userId":"1","id":null,"title":"qui est esse","body":"est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}]

Comment: _my json is not formatted correctly.._ What do you mean? Your json is totally valid - do you want to beautify it?

Comment: Are you getting errors? Can't view the array on the other end? How are you parsing it? Kindly provide us with the side which parses this.

Comment: (http://half-witted-transis.000webhostapp.com /posts.php)

Comment: @Comet check out my php code.When i am accessing that page json should be properly formatted,but it is not.I dont know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```